# ElasticSearch cluster auto relocation unbalanced

Tags: elasticsearch, relocation

I have 7 nodes in my es cluster with the same cpu and memory.
5 of them have three 1T disks, the other 2 have only one 1T disk.
I find that the shards on my cluster frequently relocate,
but the disk usage is very unbalanced, for example as below:

usage: 34%
free: 1.94TB
total: 2.95TB

usage: 55%
free: 1.33TB
total: 2.95TB

usage: 57%
free: 1.27TB
total: 2.93TB

usage: 46%
free: 1.60TB
total: 2.95TB

usage: 55%
free: 1.31TB
total: 2.93TB

usage: 90%
free: 100.40GB
total: 1007.93GB

usage: 85%
free: 152.79GB
total: 1007.93GB

1. Is it because the disk are unbalanced?
2. can i solve that by making some config?

Thank you