# ElasticSearch cluster always auto-balancing

Tags: elasticsearch, relocation

I have an issue with ES auto balancing shards in my cluster:

- I've seen it moving shards from nodes with more free disk space to nodes with less free disk space
- It has been moving shards non-stop for days, which I thought was ok until I realized it was moving them across AZs (AWS availability zones, which means: that costs money)
- I checked our nodes and they looked already quite balanced: similar shard counts and similar free disk space.

Why is ES taking the decision of moving shards then?
Is there a way to look into why ES decides to balance a shard in a certain way?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Some maybe-relevant configuration values we have set in our cluster:

```
Shard allocation settings
   cluster.routing.allocation.enable => all
   cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_incoming_recoveries => 2
   cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_outgoing_recoveries => 2
   cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries => 8
   cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries => 4
   cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host => false

Shard rebalancing settings
   cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance => indices_all_active
   cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance => 2

Shard balancing heuristics
   cluster.routing.allocation.balance.shard => 0.45
   cluster.routing.allocation.balance.index => 0.99f
   cluster.routing.allocation.balance.threshold => 1.0
```

**BTW:**

- I'm using ElasticSearch 6.8
- My data nodes already have `cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes'` set to `'aws_availability_zone'`
- I had posted two similar questions in ES' blog: "Discuss the Elastic Stack" as I didn't get answers there:

  - [ES cluster always auto-balancing](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-cluster-always-auto-balancing/210947).
  - [Cluster rebalancing across AZs](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cluster-rebalancing-across-azs/210946)
- There is a similar [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264382/elasticsearch-cluster-auto-relocation-unbalanced) but it didn't get any answers. Also, the version they were using at the start of 2017 is likely different  from the one I'm using now.

Comment: Is there any non-default settings?

Comment: We have several non-default settings, which ones could affect rebalancing in this way? I can provide their values.

Comment: @MondKin , yes please provide as much as information you can.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Amit I've edited the question to provide some configuration options that I thought may be relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the AWS elasticsearch managed service by any chance?

Comment: No, we are using the original one from elastic.co installed by ourselves on our own EC2 machines.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Kind of: Our cluster is no longer auto-rebalancing constantly, but I don't know if it's because we upgraded to ES 7.5 or because the cluster got to a point where it was happy with the shard allocations.